# Resolving OpenEBS Startup Probe Failure with Istio on Kubernetes: Connection Refused Error

Tags: kubernetes, helm, istio

I'm trying to deploy a Helm chart on my Kubernetes cluster where Istio is already installed. Here's a snippet of my Helm chart's dependencies:

```yaml
dependencies: 
- name: opensearch
  version: "0.13.0"
  repository: "https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami"
- name: openebs
  version: '3.10.0'
  repository: https://openebs.github.io/charts
```

After initiating the installation, OpenEBS successfully created a `init-pvc` pod,

[image]

but upon describing the pod, I encountered a startup probe failure with the following error:

```
Warning  Unhealthy  47s (x16 over 64s)  kubelet  Startup probe failed: Get "http://10.1.0.177:15021/healthz/ready": dial tcp 10.1.0.177:15021: connect: connection refused
```

It appears that OpenEBS is experiencing issues communicating within the Istio-injected environment, leading to this connection refused error.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue or can offer insights into what might be causing this problem and how to resolve it? Any guidance on ensuring compatibility between OpenEBS and Istio or adjusting the configuration to avoid such errors would be greatly appreciated.